# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case

Tags: sql, case

What is wrong with this Code:

```
select
ACCPMF_MDANT , ACCPMF_ACPID as " Entity ID "
from ACCPMF
where ACCPMF_BERMO = ' 202012 '

case
when ACCPMF_ASOLP = ' N ' then ' 1 '
else ' 3 '
end as " Legal proceeding status "

from ACCPMF
where ACCPMF_BERMO = ' 202012 '
```

i have following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'.

Comment: Please share more details, like the programming language you are using and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Case block should be placed in SELECT. I guess that is what you are trying to get.

Comment: Put Case block into bracket and check (case
when ACCPMF_ASOLP = 'N' then '1'
else '3'
end) as "Legal proceeding status"

Answer (score 1):

You have put the column definition starting with case after the from and where.
Try

```sql
select 
  ACCPMF_MDANT , 
  ACCPMF_ACPID as " Entity ID " ,
  case 
    when ACCPMF_ASOLP = ' N ' then ' 1 ' 
    else ' 3 ' 
    end as " Legal proceeding status 
from 
  ACCPMF 
where 
  ACCPMF_BERMO = ' 202012 ';
```

Answer (score 0):

From your query I guess that ACCPMF_ASOLP is also a field of your table. The error that you have is that the WHERE clause should be after the selected columns / case instruction that you want to get; so the first FROM + WHERE has to be at the end:

```
select 
ACCPMF_MDANT , ACCPMF_ACPID as " Entity ID ",
case
when ACCPMF_ASOLP = ' N ' then ' 1 '
else ' 3 '
end as " Legal proceeding status "
from ACCPMF
where ACCPMF_BERMO = ' 202012 '
```

Note that I've ignored the fact that you are comparing string values with ' x ' for example instead of '1' (without the blank spaces), I assume that ' N ', ' 1 '... are the value you really need